# Order of transactions on database

Tags: database, transactions

I have a question on db transactions.
I have a page of a Web Application that shows an input form. If two clients are submitting that form in the same moment, the transactions executed on the db to save sent data are executed sequentially? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes.
Do you have a timestamp in your transaction? You can verify it with that.
Depends on what database you are using this should be handled internally by database engine.

Comment: I am using MySQL for test and MariaDB in production (it's a long story) and I do not have a timestamp attribute at the moment. My question was born from a concurrency problem because i have this table where (i don't know why) the developer used a surrogate key instead of a natural one. I cannot change the db structure so i have to make controls in the code i'm writing to avoid duplications. So i was wondering what would happen if two users sends the same data, at the same time but only one of those form should be saved...
Hope i've been clear enough.